# Centos port redirection

Tags: centos, port-forwarding

I would like to forward my port 22 to another machine. So the whole ssh will be handled by another machine.

This is what I've tried:
`sudo /sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination <myip>:22`

This seemed to be working, but when I tried to connect using ssh, the connection was waiting and nothing happens. Any clue?

Comment: Have you enabled `ip_forward` and added a corresponding rule to the `FORWARD` table to allow the traffic? Does <myip> actually accept SSH connections? What are the actual addresses? You may have asynchronous routing issues.

Comment: ip_forward is enabled, but what is the FORWARD rule? It isn't what I've added to my post? <myip> does accept SSH connections. Actual addresses? What do you mean by this? How to detect if I have asynchronous routing issues?

Comment: The rule you've added only does the redirection. You still have to allow it to actually pass through your box in the FORWARD chain: `iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp --dport 22 -d <myip> -j ACCEPT`

Comment: I've tried this, but it doesn't appear when I run this command: `sudo /sbin/iptables -t nat -n -L`. Also it isn't working. Did I do something else wrong? The problem remains the same after your command.

Comment: when I said "actual addresses" I meant what at the actual IP addresses? ie, you're not actually forwarding to "<myip>". What is the IP address of the host you're running the iptables commands on? You can see if async routing is possibly an issue by adding this rule to iptables: `iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -d <myip> -p tcp --dport ssh -j MASQUERADE` and then try the connection again.

Comment: The <myip> is a publicly accessible IP address. Both computers are on separate network and can access each other by the internet. Is this ok?

Comment: Not enough enough information to be able to say. Edit your original post to add as much information as possible. Hiding your IP addresses does nothing for security. If they're on port 22, they're going to get hammered by brute-forcing anyway.

Answer (score 0):

as stated, do a

> cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

to make sure your have ip packet forwarding/routing enabled

also, check to see your destination redirection target is actually accessible.   hanging for a long time (ie 2 minutes) is typically a sign of firewalling in place dropping/denying your packets.

it could also be a dns issue, so make sure your dns entries resolve correctly if using that.

lastly, as suggested, do a show ip route and make sure there are no overlaps between the network you are trying to get to and any intermediary private networks.... you can chack this with traceroute

Comment: Yes, I'v tested the cat... and it's ok, it is enabled. My redirection target is actually accessible through <myip>. It hangs only when I try to access it through the machine that is doing the forwarding. The DNS can't be an issue in this case, because I am using IP addresses. I will try the traceroute. Thanks!